# How can I get the number of affected records, and just that, using mysql cmdline?

Tags: mysql, shell, command-line, output, verbosity

I'm running the `mysql` cmdline binary to execute queries. (Specifically, I'm executing 
`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`). I would like to have it print, after every statement, the number of records effected - but no other lines. I don't mind the line containing other info, e.g.

```
Query OK, 20 rows affected, 4 warnings
```

would be great. I can, in fact, get that - but only if I use the `-v -v` pair of switches, and then I get more info which I don't need, like an echo of the parsed command.

Can I do anything other than `grep` the output for the pattern of the line above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's maybe not the best solution, but you can try the SQL [ROW_COUNT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count) function

E.g :

```
mysql ... -e "YOUR_QUERY;SELECT ROW_COUNT()" -B | tail -n 1
```

Comment: What are the drawbacks of doing it this way?

Comment: None, (or I do not know) but there is maybe a solution directly with mysql cli.